# Unable to import matplotlib.pyplot on Python 3 (MacOS)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I installed Python 3 on MacOS Mojavie 10.14 using:

```
brew install python3
```

Then using the following command I installed matplotlib

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

Importing matplotlib.pyplot is successful on Python 2:

[Python2 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLXdH.png)

but fails on Python 3:

[Python3 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eNfg.png)

I have tried reinstalling python3 and matplotlib but failed. Could not find a solution.

Comment: Could you please provide your errors in text form (not images) such that people searching for this bug would have a chance to find it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in matplotlib 3.0.0,

- https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12173
- https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12439

which will be fixed in an upcoming 3.0.1 release.

- https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12213

In `lib/matplotlib/font_manager.py`:

[image]

Alternatively, downgrade to matplotlib 2.2.3 until 3.0.1 is released.